# How to differentiate two data sets returned by the same custom interface method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

To elaborate, I'm using interface to return the list of hashmaps from AsyncTask into my Activity. AsyncTask is triggered in the Activity itself and result is catched within implemented interface method.

```
// This triggers AsyincTask in onCreate method of the Activity
JSONparser.executeParser(url, Profile.this);

// OnPostExecute returns data through interface method
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String downloadedData) {
            super.onPostExecute(downloadedData);

            // If web service returned data
            if (!downloadedData.equals("")) {

                JSONObject jObject;

                try {
                    // Put data into JSON Object and pass it to parser
                    jObject = new JSONObject(downloadedData);
                    parsedData = ParseJSONData.parse(jObject);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("ParserException", e.toString());
                }

                asyncInterface.onTaskFinished(parsedData);

            }else{
                asyncInterface.onTaskFinished(null);
            }
        }

//In activity I catch data from implemented interface and set up ListView
@Override
    public void onTaskFinished(List<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyHelper.getNotifications(context, notifications, data);
    }
```

**My question is, how would I differentiate returned data in this interface method if i would to trigger two AsyncTasks in my Activity?**

For example if i would like to get data from two different web services:

```
// This triggers AsyincTask in onCreate method of the Activity
JSONparser.executeParser(url1, Profile.this);
JSONparser.executeParser(url2, Profile.this);
```

How would I differentiate data from url1 and data from url2 in interface method?

```
@Override
public void onTaskFinished(List<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: By what they contain?  In what manner would you like to be differentiating them?

Comment: I've updated question with additional example

Comment: If you can't simply refactor to pass the url the same way you're passing data then just shove the URL in data and pop it out later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use instead of **List data parameter** some wrapper, that will contain your List data and additional information about it (for example hash code of url).

Also please use

```
"".equals(downloadedData)
```

instead of

```
downloadedData.equals("")
```

because if `downloadedData` is `null`...

Answer (score 0):

Pass your AsyncTask back in your listener ...

```
@Override
public void onTaskFinished(AsyncTask task, List<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

    if(task == myFirstTask) then ... 


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MyHelper.getNotifications(context, notifications, data);
}
```

Comment: I've passed int "responseCode" in my listener, so when I call AsyncTask i do it like this JSONparser.executeParser(url1, Profile.this, int responseCode1) or JSONparser.executeParser(url2, Profile.this, int responseCode2) and then in onTaskFinished(int responseCode, List<HashMap<String, String>> data) I do switch on response code to catch results on all tasks. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: What you switch on doesn't matter much, if it works. The thing is, you already have the asynctask object which you can pass back and forth, you don't need the "artificial" int and now you have to even make conversions between int and asynctask. I don't think it's neccessary, but if it works, good for you :)